# swf is playing sounds while it is loaded before adding it onto stage in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im loading a swf which contains sounds on frames and that sounds start playing while it loading before adding it onto the stage... The code used for loading and adding swf is as below...

```
private function loadSWF(path:String):void
        {
            var _req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            _req.url = path;

            _swfLoader = new URLLoader();
            setupListeners(_swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo);

            _swfLoader.load(_req);
        }

private function setupListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void
        {
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addSWF);
        }

        private function addSWF(event:Event):void
        {
            event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addSWF);
            event.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preloadSWF);

            _swfLoader.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onLoadComp);

            _swfContent = event.currentTarget.content;
            stage.addEventListener("close", unloadSWF);

            stage.addChild(_swfLoader); 
        }
```

Plz help...

Comment: Is your question, you don't want the music to play until its loaded?

Answer (score 0):

try with `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event Listener, i think it would work.